# C++ Rectangle Not Positioned Correctly When Adjusting Speed Value?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to fabricate a smoothscrolling function which makes a rectangle move up and down the screen to the desired option in a smooth manner.

For this effect I use the following function, which is called in a loop:

```
float scrollBarPos;
void Menu::smoothScroller() {
    float toPos;
    if (optionCount > maxOptions) {
        if (currentOption > maxOptions) {
            toPos = ((maxOptions * 0.035f) + 0.1765f);
        } else {
            toPos = ((currentOption * 0.035f) + 0.1765f);
        }
    } else {
        toPos = ((currentOption * 0.035f) + 0.1765f);
    }
    if (scrollBarPos > toPos) {
        scrollBarPos -= 0.0005f;
    }
    if (scrollBarPos < toPos) {
        scrollBarPos += 0.0005f;
    }
}
```

Now to draw the rectangle, I use:

```
GRAPHICS::DRAW_SPRITE("commonmenu", "gradient_nav", pos, scrollBarPos, 0.23f, 0.035f, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255);
```

Where `scrollBarPos` is the float of the `smoothScroller` function.

**The problem:** `scrollBarPos` either increases or decreases with `0.0005f`. That's very slow, but the rectangle is drawn correctly on screen. When changing it to `0.0200f`, it scrolls at a great speed but somehow goes out of place.

What could be the problem here?

---

[image]

Comment: How much is it offset by? If I had to guess, the decreased precision of moving it by `0.0200f` means that it is making larger steps and not able to position itself as accurately as when it makes smaller `0.0005f` steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
if (scrollBarPos > toPos) {
    scrollBarPos -= 0.0005f;
}
if (scrollBarPos < toPos) {
    scrollBarPos += 0.0005f;
}
```

to:

```
if (std::fabs(scrollBarPos - toPos) < 0.0200f) {
    scrollBarPos = toPos;
} else {
    if (scrollBarPos > toPos) {
        scrollBarPos -= 0.0200f;
    } else if (scrollBarPos < toPos) {
        scrollBarPos += 0.0200f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a ton Georgi!